# Is it possible to have both Pub/Sub and BigQuery as inputs in Google Dataflow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

In my project, I am looking to use a streaming pipeline in Google Dataflow in order to process Pub/Sub messages. In cleaning the input data, I am looking to also have a side input from BigQuery. This has presented a problem that will cause one of the two inputs to not work.

I have set in my Pipeline options for streaming=True, which allows the Pub/Sub inputs to process properly. But BigQuery is not compatible with streaming pipelines (see link below):

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#what_are_the_current_limitations_of_streaming_mode

I received this error: "ValueError: Cloud Pub/Sub is currently available for use only in streaming pipelines." This is understandable based on the limitations.

But I am only looking to use BigQuery as a side input in order to map data to the incoming Pub/Sub data stream. It works fine locally, but once I try to run it on Dataflow, it returns the error.

Has anyone found a good workaround for this?

EDIT: adding the framework of my pipeline below for reference:

```
# Set all options needed to properly run the pipeline
options = PipelineOptions(streaming=True,
                          runner='DataflowRunner', 
                          project=project_id)

p = beam.Pipeline(options = options)

n_tbl_src = (p
         | 'Nickname Table Read' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(
            table = nickname_spec
        )))

# This is the main Dataflow pipeline. This will clean the incoming dataset for importing into BQ.
clean_vote = (p
              | beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(topic = None,
                                     subscription = 'projects/{0}/subscriptions/{1}'
                                                  .format(project_id, subscription_name),
                                     with_attributes = True)
              | 'Isolate Attributes' >> beam.ParDo(IsolateAttrFn())
              | 'Fix Value Types' >> beam.ParDo(FixTypesFn())
              | 'Scrub First Name' >> beam.ParDo(ScrubFnameFn())
              | 'Fix Nicknames' >> beam.ParDo(FixNicknameFn(), n_tbl=AsList(n_tbl_src))
              | 'Scrub Last Name' >> beam.ParDo(ScrubLnameFn()))


# The final dictionary will then be written to BigQuery for storage
(clean_vote | 'Write to BQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
    table = bq_spec,
    write_disposition = beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    create_disposition = beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER
))

# Run the pipeline
p.run()
```

Comment: So you want to query BQ every time a window gets triggered, right? You could do this by accessing BQ directly through the BQ API, and use that. The Beam BQ source currently works only in batch pipelines unfortunately.

Comment: @Pablo That did it! I assumed that to run in the pipeline, it had initially be a part of the pipeline, but good to know that it doesn't. Appreciate the help. It's that kind of outside of the box thinking that gets the job done!

Answer (score 2):

@Pablo's comment above was the correct answer. For anyone working through the same situation, below is the change in my script that worked.

```
# This opens the Beam pipeline to run Dataflow
p = beam.Pipeline(options = options)
logging.info('Created Dataflow pipeline.')

# This will pull in all of the recorded nicknames to compare to the incoming PubSubMessages.

client = bigquery.Client()
query_job = client.query("""
    select * from `{0}.{1}.{2}`""".format(project_id, dataset_id, nickname_table_id))
nickname_tbl = query_job.result()
nickname_tbl = [dict(row.items()) for row in nickname_tbl]

# This is the main Dataflow pipeline. This will clean the incoming dataset for importing into BQ.
clean_vote = (p
              | beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(topic = None,
                                     subscription = 'projects/{0}/subscriptions/{1}'
                                                  .format(project_id, subscription_name),
                                     with_attributes = True)
              | 'Isolate Attributes' >> beam.ParDo(IsolateAttrFn())
              | 'Fix Value Types' >> beam.ParDo(FixTypesFn())
              | 'Scrub First Name' >> beam.ParDo(ScrubFnameFn())
              | 'Fix Nicknames' >> beam.ParDo(FixNicknameFn(), n_tbl=nickname_tbl)
              | 'Scrub Last Name' >> beam.ParDo(ScrubLnameFn()))


# The final dictionary will then be written to BigQuery for storage
(clean_vote | 'Write to BQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
    table = bq_spec,
    write_disposition = beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    create_disposition = beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER
))

# Run the pipeline
p.run()
```